# Variable undefined in Javascript, help to make it correct

Tags: javascript, oop, error-handling

I'm coding a basic rock paper scissors game.

the  2 functions are working fine. the issue is the winner variable is always undefined..

I don't know what to do to correct this. I want it to say who won, computer or the human(user).

```
function game(x, y) {
    var inputC = computerPlay();
    var inputH = humanPlay();
    var winner;

    if (inputH == 'paper' && inputC == 'scissors') {
        console.log('Computer wins with Scissors ');

        if (inputH == 'scissors' && inputC == 'rock') {
            console.log('Computer wins with rock');

            if (inputC == 'paper' && inputH == 'rock') {
                console.log('Computer wins with paper');
            }
        }

        winner = "computer";
    } else if (inputC == 'paper' && inputH == 'scissors') {
        console.log('Human wins with Scissors ');

        if (inputC == 'scissors' && inputH == 'rock') {
            console.log('Human wins with rock');

            if (inputH == 'paper' && inputC == 'rock') {
                console.log('Human wins with paper');
            }
        }
        winner = "human";
    }
    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = winner;
    console.log("result is: " + winner + " wins");
}
```

I'm sure its something minor but my god I'm all out of ideas.

Comment: your conditions are badly nested ... the only time winner will be defined is if `inputH == 'paper' && inputC == 'scissors'` or `inputC == 'paper' && inputH == 'scissors'` all other combinations will result in winner being undefined ... don't nest if's like that without understanding

Comment: thanks for the advice man, totally agree. tbh this was one of my many attempts to get around winner being undefined. 


 if (inputH == 'paper' && inputC == 'scissors') {
console.log('Computer wins with Scissors ');
 winner = "computer";
  }

else if (inputC == 'paper' && inputH == 'scissors') {
console.log('Human wins with Scissors ');
winner = "human";
 }


this is the original look( its goes through all the conditions but I shortened it here to fit)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

would like this

```
function game() {
    var inputC = computerPlay();
    var inputH = humanPlay();
    var winner = "human";

    if (inputH === inputC) {
       winner = "nobody";
    } else if ((inputH === 'paper' && inputC === 'scissors') ||
        (inputH === 'scissors' && inputC === 'rock') ||
        (inputH === 'rock' && inputC === 'paper')
    ) {
        console.log('Computer wins with ' + inputC);
        winner = "computer";
    } else {
        console.log('Human wins with ' + inputH);
    }

    document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = winner;
    console.log("result is: " + winner + " wins");
}
```

Comment: not really ... I'd have `else if (inputH == inputC) { winner = 'nobody';}` then the else where human wins, to be accurate :p

Comment: that's not a flaw in your logic per se, I mean the original code had the same problem :p

Comment: thanks again. I should have caught it at the first place :-)

Comment: two equals works too. IMO, It is a good habit to be strict on comparing variables

Answer (score 2):

it was `undefined` because it didn't go to either one of condition.

Another alternative answer from me

```
function game(x, y) {
  var inputC = computerPlay();
  var inputH = humanPlay();

  var isComputerWin = 
    (inputC == 'scissors' && inputH == 'paper') ||
    (inputC == 'rock' && inputH == 'scissors') ||
    (inputC == 'paper' && inputH == 'rock');

  var winner = isComputerWin ? 'computer' : 'human';
  var winnerWith = isComputerWin ? inputC : inputH;
  console.log(winner + " wins with " + winnerWith);

  document.getElementById("text1").innerHTML = winner;  
  console.log("result is: " + winner + " wins");
}
```